# GStreamer emits not-linked error even when elements are already linked

Tags: rust, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to create a capture-to-streaming pipeline with GStreamer but after creating the pipeline and linking all of the elements, I still get warnings that the source elements are not linked, even though the dot file for the pipeline shows that they are.

Code:

```rust
//TODO: Send all logs to tracing and filter from there instead of using gstreamer filter
//gst::debug_set_default_threshold(gst::DebugLevel::Count);
tracing_gstreamer::integrate_events();
gst::debug_remove_default_log_function();
gst::init()?;
tracing_gstreamer::integrate_spans();
*HANDLES_COUNT.lock().unwrap() += 1;

//Create a new GStreamer pipeline
let pipeline = gst::Pipeline::new(None);

//--VIDEO--

//Create a new ximagesrc to get video from the X server
let ximagesrc = gst::ElementFactory::make("ximagesrc", None)?;

let videoscale = gst::ElementFactory::make("videoscale", None)?;

//Creating a capsfilter to set the resolution and the fps
let capsfilter = gst::ElementFactory::make("capsfilter", None)?;

let fps_frac = gst::Fraction::new(fps, 1);

//Create a vector containing the option of the gst caps
let mut caps_options: Vec<(&str, &(dyn ToSendValue + Sync))> = vec![("framerate", &fps_frac)];

//If the resolution is specified, add it to the caps
let width = resolution.width as i32;
let height = resolution.height as i32;
if resolution.is_fixed {
    caps_options.push(("width", &width));
    caps_options.push(("height", &height));
};


capsfilter.set_property("caps", &gst::Caps::new_simple(
    "video/x-raw",
    caps_options.as_ref()
));

ximagesrc.set_property_from_str("show-pointer", "1");
//Set xid based on constructor parameter to get video only from the specified X window
ximagesrc.set_property("xid", xid as u64);

//Create a new videoconvert to allow encoding of the raw video
let videoconvert = gst::ElementFactory::make("videoconvert", None)?;

//Chose encoder and rtp encapsulator based on constructor params
let (encoder, encoder_pay) = match encoder_to_use {
    VideoEncoderType::H264(settings) => {
        (
            //Use nvidia encoder based on settings
            if settings.nvidia_encoder {
                gst::ElementFactory::make("nvh264enc", None)?
            } else {
                gst::ElementFactory::make("x264enc", None)?
            },
            gst::ElementFactory::make("rtph264pay", None)?
        )
    }
    VideoEncoderType::VP8 => {
        (
            gst::ElementFactory::make("vp8enc", None)?,
            gst::ElementFactory::make("rtpvp8pay", None)?
        )
    }
    VideoEncoderType::VP9 => {
        (
            gst::ElementFactory::make("vp9enc", None)?,
            gst::ElementFactory::make("rtpvp9pay", None)?
        )
    }
};

encoder_pay.set_property("ssrc", video_ssrc);


//--AUDIO--

// Caps filter for audio from conversion to encoding
let audio_capsfilter = gst::ElementFactory::make("capsfilter", None)?;

//Create a vector containing the option of the gst caps
let caps_options: Vec<(&str, &(dyn ToSendValue + Sync))> = vec![("channels", &2), ("rate", &48000)];

audio_capsfilter.set_property("caps", &gst::Caps::new_simple(
    "audio/x-raw",
    caps_options.as_ref()
));

//Create a new pulsesrc to get audio from the PulseAudio server
let pulsesrc = gst::ElementFactory::make("pulsesrc", None)?;
//Set the audio device based on constructor parameter (should be the sink of the audio application)
pulsesrc.set_property_from_str("device", "tuxphones.monitor");

//Create a new audioconvert to allow encoding of the raw audio
let audioconvert = gst::ElementFactory::make("audioconvert", None)?;
//Encoder for the raw audio to opus
let opusenc = gst::ElementFactory::make("opusenc", None)?;
//Opus encapsulator for rtp
let rtpopuspay = gst::ElementFactory::make("rtpopuspay", None)?;
rtpopuspay.set_property("ssrc", audio_ssrc);


//--DESTINATION--

//mux
let rtpmux = gst::ElementFactory::make("rtpmux", None)?;
rtpmux.set_property("ssrc", rtx_ssrc);
rtpmux.add_pad(&gst::GhostPad::new(Some("vsink"), gst::PadDirection::Sink))?;
rtpmux.add_pad(&gst::GhostPad::new(Some("asink"), gst::PadDirection::Sink))?;
let video_sink = rtpmux.static_pad("vsink").unwrap();
let audio_sink = rtpmux.static_pad("asink").unwrap();

//encryption
let srtpenc = gst::ElementFactory::make("srtpenc", None)?;
srtpenc.set_property_from_str("rtcp-cipher", encryption_algorithm.to_gst_str());
srtpenc.set_property("key", gst::Buffer::from_slice(key));
srtpenc.add_pad(&gst::GhostPad::new(Some("src"), gst::PadDirection::Src))?;

//Create a new webrtcbin to connect the pipeline to the WebRTC peer
let webrtcbin = gst::ElementFactory::make("webrtcbin", None)?;
webrtcbin.add_pad(&gst::GhostPad::new(Some("sink"), gst::PadDirection::Sink))?;

let mut sdp = SDPMessage::new();
sdp.set_connection("IN", "IP4", discord_address, 1, 1);

let webrtc_desc = WebRTCSessionDescription::new(
    WebRTCSDPType::Offer,
    sdp
);
webrtcbin.emit_by_name::<()>("set-remote-description", &[&webrtc_desc, &None::<gst::Promise>]);

//Add elements to the pipeline
pipeline.add_many(&[
    &ximagesrc, &videoscale, &capsfilter, &videoconvert, &encoder, &encoder_pay,
    &pulsesrc, &audioconvert, &audio_capsfilter, &opusenc, &rtpopuspay,
    &rtpmux, &srtpenc,
    &webrtcbin])?;

//Link video elements
Element::link_many(&[&ximagesrc, &videoscale, &capsfilter, &videoconvert, &encoder, &encoder_pay])?;

//Link audio elements
Element::link_many(&[&pulsesrc, &audioconvert, &audio_capsfilter, &opusenc, &rtpopuspay])?;

rtpmux.link(&srtpenc)?;
srtpenc.link(&webrtcbin)?;
//gst::Pad::link(&srtpenc.static_pad("rtp_src_0").unwrap(), &webrtcbin.static_pad("sink").unwrap())?;

//Link encoderpay to rtpmux video sink
gst::Pad::link(&encoder_pay.static_pad("src").unwrap(), &video_sink)?;

//Link rtpopuspay to rtpmux audio sink
gst::Pad::link(&rtpopuspay.static_pad("src").unwrap(), &audio_sink)?;

// Generate dot file (not shown)
```

After this is run, the pipeline is started immediately after:

```rust
self.pipeline.set_state(gst::State::Playing)
```

Log:

```
2022-07-01T16:23:02.640204Z  WARN gstreamer::basesrc: error: Internal data stream error. gobject.address=140187265069712 gobject.type="GstPulseSrc" gstobject.name="pulsesrc0" gstelement.state="playing" gstelement.pending_state="void-pending"
2022-07-01T16:23:02.640245Z  WARN gstreamer::basesrc: error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1) gobject.address=140187265069712 gobject.type="GstPulseSrc" gstobject.name="pulsesrc0" gstelement.state="playing" gstelement.pending_state="void-pending"
2022-07-01T16:23:04.806453Z  WARN gstreamer::basesrc: error: Internal data stream error. gobject.address=140187264845024 gobject.type="GstXImageSrc" gstobject.name="ximagesrc0" gstelement.state="playing" gstelement.pending_state="void-pending"
2022-07-01T16:23:04.806520Z  WARN gstreamer::basesrc: error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1) gobject.address=140187264845024 gobject.type="GstXImageSrc" gstobject.name="ximagesrc0" gstelement.state="playing" gstelement.pending_state="void-pending"
```

Rendered Dot File:
[image: GStreamer Pipeline]

Rendered dot file after negotiation:
[image: GStreamer Pipeline Negotiated]

What am I not doing correctly here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will probably work if you get rid of the `rtpmux` and `srtpenc`, and instead link the RTP payloaders directly to (two!) `webrtcbin` sink pads.

`webrtcbin` is doing everything after RTP payloading internally, including bundling (what you seem to try with `rtpmux` here) and SRTP encryption.

If you look at the debug logs you'll see that `webrtcbin` simply doesn't know what to do with the incoming SRTP stream and because of that doesn't link it further internally but instead just leaves it unlinked.